# res.render in node with controller response to jade

Tags: node.js, pug, sequelize.js

this is a part of my model

```
router.get('/subscription', function (req, res, next) {
    var membership = require('../controllers/membership.js');
   var jData = membership.getAll(req, res);
   res.render('subscription', { title: 'Subscription', data : jData });
});
```

this is a part of my controller.js

```
var db = require('../db.js');

module.exports = {
    //home: function (req, res, next) {
    //    res.send('home page');
    //},
    insert: function (req, res) {
        var body = req.body; //_.pick(req.body, 'description', 'completed');

        db.membership.create(body).then(function (membership) {
            res.json(membership.toJSON());
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).json(e);
        });
    },
    updateById: function (req, res, next) {
        //var Id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
        var body = req.body;

        db.membership.update(body, { where: { id: parseInt(_.propertyOf(body)('id'), 10) } }).then(function (membership) {
            if (!!membership) {
                res.json(membership.toJSON());
            } else {
                res.status(404).send();
            }
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).json(e);
        });
    },
    deleteById: function (req, res, next) {
        //var Id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);
        var body = req.body;

        db.membership.destroy({ where: { id: parseInt(_.propertyOf(body)('id'), 10) } }).then(function (membership) {
            if (!!membership) {
                console.log('The Row with the Id : ' + _.propertyOf(body)('id') + ' deleted successfully!');
            } else {
                res.status(404).send();
            }
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).json(e);
        });
    },
    deleteAll: function (req, res, next) {
        db.membership.truncate().then(function () {
            console.log('All rows deleted successfully!');
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).json(e);
        });
    },
    getById: function (req, res) {
        var Id = parseInt(req.params.id, 10);

        db.membership.findById(Id).then(function (membership) {
            if (!!membership) {
                console.log('\n\nMEMBERSHIP : ' + JSON.stringify(membership.toJSON()));
                res.json(membership.toJSON());
                //return membership.toJSON();
            } else {
                res.status(404).send();
            }
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).send();
        });

    },
    getAll: function (req, res) {

        var where = {};

        db.membership.findAll({
            where: where
        }).then(function (membership) {
            res.json(membership.toJSON());
        }, function (e) {
            res.status(500).send();
        });

    }
};
```

i am trying to get aal data in my model data comes perfectly so no issue in controller
but res.render function data could not be passed to jade.
according to me res.render function call before jdata variable filled.
any solution about it tell me.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send the response two times, if you send the res in the controller you can't send it again in the model, you should use a callback:

Controller:

```
getAll: function(cb) {
    var where = {};
    db.membership.findAll({
        where: where
    }).then(function(membership) {
        cb({
            data: membership.toJSON()
        });
    }, function(e) {
        cb({
            error: e
        });
    });
}
```

Model:

```
router.get('/subscription', function (req, res, next) {
    var membership = require('../controllers/membership.js');
    var jData = membership.getAll(function (cb) {
        if (cb.error) res.status(400).send();
        res.render('subscription', { title: 'Subscription', data : cb.data });
    });
});
```